# CesiumJS: Draggable points jump to static point locations

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I've written a few functions to draw draggable and static points in Cesium. However, I have a big issue when using these together.

I can draw draggable points by clicking on the map, and move them around by clicking and dragging. But if I plot a static point after plotting a draggable point, the draggable point jumps to the location of the static point! I can still drag the point, but it always snaps back to the static points location.

Here's a Sandcastle demo to illustrate my problem - http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=54a2252d95768ca89d23948ad010356a

In this example, any click on the map will create a draggable point (red points). There are two timeouts at the end of the script, one of which will draw a static point after 5s, and the other will plot a static point at a different location after 10s. The static points are purple and a lot smaller than the draggable ones.

As you'll see, if you draw a draggable point in the first 5s, it will jump to the location of the first static point.

What's going on?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rachel Hwang from the Cesium team solved this for me. Here's her solution:

> This:
>
> ```
>  let positionCallback = () => {
>
>      return waypointPosition;
>
> };
> ```
>
> Should be:
>
> ```
>  let positionCallback = (time, result) => {
>
>     return waypointPosition.clone(result);
>
> };
> ```
>
> The reason is that the signature for the CallbackProperty callback (https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/CallbackProperty.html#~Callback)
>   takes a time and result.  If result is provided then you MUST store
>   the result into that existing object and return it (otherwise you
>   should return a new value).  Calling clone(result) does just that. 
>   The reason it is done this way is because we make heavy use of scratch
>   variables to avoid memory allocations.

The Sandcastle now works as required - http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=54a2252d95768ca89d23948ad010356a